# Is it possible to clone a git repository using ssh/git protocol from KIE Drools Workbench

Tags: java, git, drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I have a maven module on my git repo which contains rules files (.drl).
I would like to clone this repository from KIE Drools Workbench.

When I go to Authoring -> Administration -> Repositories -> Clone Repository and gave the git url using **https** protocol it is able to clone successfully.

But if I try to clone using git or ssh protocol I am getting error message as:

> Can't clone repository.
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NotSupportedException:URI not supported:
>   ssh:///github.com:sivaprasadreddy/myrep.git

I have tried with the following git URLs and are NOT working:
**git://github.com:sivaprasadreddy/myrep.git**
**ssh://github.com:sivaprasadreddy/myrep.git**

KIE Drools Workbench supports only https based cloning? Is there any other way to clone my git repo using ssh protocol from KIE Workbench?